# Is the FAA's International Flight Information Manual available for download? If so, from where?

Tags: faa, publications

[This FAA website](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/systemops/fs/alaskan/alaska/fai/pubs) indicates that the "International Flight Information Manual (IFIM)" is a downloadable publication of the FAA.

I've never heard of this manual before today, and would like to download a copy of it.  However, clicking the provided link takes me to [this page](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications), which doesn't seem to mention the IFIM at all.

Have I missed spotting it?  Is it available for download from somewhere else?  Or is this a mistake or outdated information?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an International Flight Information Manual, but there used to be an International Flight Information Manager (IFIM), which was discontinued on November 14, 2014. Here is [an archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160429221455/http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/ifim/) mentioning its discontinuation. It seems likely that this is the same document.